# Synchronizing data between desktop and WinPhone versions of application

Tags: synchronization, windows-phone-8.1, infrastructure

I've got a desktop application and a corresponding windows phone universal/store app, which both use the same data file.

Ideally what I'd like to do is have both versions save to a Dropbox-style folder, so the synchronization is done 'automatically' for me, but as far as I can tell, a winphone app can't just go and pick up files from anywhere without user interaction: and I don't want to force the user to do a manual pick for every synchronisation.

I guess I could use the Dropbox API via internet, but is there a more elegant solution that I'm missing?

Comment: If your data is not too big, then you can probably use [Roaming app data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700362.aspx), [here also are some guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/apps/hh465094.aspx).

Comment: When you say desktop, do you mean WPF app or a Windows Store app?

Comment: @igrali, WPF, which eliminates roaming data as a possibility, if I understood it correctly

Answer (score 0):

The solution you're missing is roaming data API.

> Windows Store and Windows Phone Store apps address this need with the concept of roaming data. Every app automatically receives a small amount of cloud storage per user. The user can use this to save information about the app and share it across multiple installs of the app.
>
> One of the nicer aspects of using roaming data in your apps is that it’s automatically available and it requires no configuration or other settings.

Taken from this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn857358.aspx